# Array of function pointers for the Windows Messages Procedure

Tags: c++, pointers

everybody
I wanna try something and I need a little help. What I want to do is to create some functions, store their pointer into an array, then calling them inside the Windows Messages Procedure. For example:

```
int create_functions[10];
int paint_functions[10];

int func1() {
    // code
}

void func2(int arg1) {
    // code
}

create_functions[0] = *func1; // add pointer of func1 to the first array
create_functions[1] = *func2; // add pointer of func2 to the second array

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            // execute create_functions[0] - How do I do it?
        case WM_PAINT:
            // execute paint_functions[0] - How do I do it?
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
             return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
             break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I know somebody will ask: why just don't execute the func1/func2 directly. Because I will decide what functions to be executed at run-time. Thanks to everybody for your help!

**EDITED:**
What about call-back functions? I don't understand very well how to use them?

Answer (score 3):

If the question is: How can I do function pointers, I suggest you look at articles on the topic such as http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

If this is not your question, can you please edit and add more details.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's what I wanna find out

Answer (score 2):

This

```
int create_functions[10];
int paint_functions[10];
```

should be

```
void (*create_functions[10])(void);
void (*create_functions[10])(int);
```

and

```
// execute create_functions[0] - How do I do it?
// execute paint_functions[0] - How do I do it?
```

should be

```
create_functions[0]();
paint_functions[0](some_integer_here);
```

Also

```
create_functions[0] = *func1; // add pointer of func1 to the first array
create_functions[1] = *func2; // add pointer of func2 to the second array
```

should be

```
create_functions[0] = func1; // add pointer of func1 to the first array
create_functions[1] = func2; // add pointer of func2 to the second array
```

or

```
create_functions[0] = &func1; // add pointer of func1 to the first array
create_functions[1] = &func2; // add pointer of func2 to the second array
```

according to your taste or mood.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the pointer to your array in wParam.